# Wordpress migration, 404 error on CSS and JS using link with two urls EX. http://example.com/http://example.com/wp-content/.../style.css

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, migration

I am attempting to completely copy a Wordpress site from one domain to another. I have moved the database, with a find and replace of old domain to the new domain. The files have been copied over.

I am getting most of the functionality just not the css and js from the old site. 
It is trying to link to JS CSS and pictures by http://example.com/http://example.com/wp-content/.../style.css with the two URL stacked up next to each other.

Here is an example of the error [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MvJi.png)

Comment: If you could post the code being used to enqueue the resources that would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify your "siteurl" and "home" parameters in the database table "wp_options" (through phpMyAdmin or similar).

Try to disable your .htaccess and also go to the Administration > Settings > Permalinks screen and update your Permalink structure.

See documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress

Comment: Ahh thank you very much, the "siteurl" and "home" parameters were messed up